# GPS location is fetched after second click not on first click

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps

I want to fetch live gps location using javscript to store it in database. I already have implemented it. when user clicks on button. But it fetches location on second click.
**Html code**

```
<form action="user_location" method="post" id="form-{{$user->id}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="location" id="location-{{$user->id}}">
</form>
<a onclick="getLocation({{$user->id}})" class="btn">{{__('Get Location')}}</a>
```

**Javscript code**

```
function getLocation(user_id) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            
        } else { 
            geolocation = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
        
        if(setlocation){
            form = document.getElementById("form-"+user_id);
            var b = document.getElementById("location-"+user_id)
            b.value = x.textContent;
            form.submit();
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerText = position.coords.latitude + "-" + position.coords.longitude;
        setlocation = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getCurrentPosition` function is asynchronous. That means that when it is called, it will allow the code after it to run before finishing. So that means that `setLocation` will not be `true` whenever your code reaches the following `if` statement:

```
if(setlocation){ // setlocation is still false
```

Handle your results of getting the position *inside* the success callback of `getCurrentPosition`.

```
function getLocation(user_id) {
  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    return;
  }

  const form = document.getElementById("form-" + user_id);
  const location = document.getElementById("location-" + user_id);

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {   
    const { coords } = position; 
    location.value = coords.latitude + "-" + coords.longitude;
    form.submit();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explaining it as well. Understood it as well because of you. Its working now